# Zend / PHP / Apache2 - problem when I run my apache server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

First of all, sorry i will try my best to explain you the problem because i am not an english poeple. 
So, last week i installed apache, php and zend, and all was working perfectly, but today when i tried to lunch the server i got a problem. I am just starting with Zend and for me it's the nothingness. Could you please help me to correct this.

This is the problem :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message ' 
Zend_Session::start() - D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:469): Error #2 session_start() [<a 
href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: 
open(C:\Windows\sess_9q7bhlv36pc8o7vhngpptmmca7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission 
denied (13) Array D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close() 
[<a href='function.session-write-close'>function.session-write-close</a>]: 
open(C:\Windows\sess_9q7bhlv36pc8o7vhngpptmmca7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission 
denied (13) Array D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close() 
[<a href='function.session-write-close'>function.session-write-close</a>]: 
Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting 
of session.save_path is correct () Array' in D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session.php:482 Stack trace: #0 D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session\Namesp in D:\Zend\ZendFramework- 
1.11.10\library\Zend\Session.php on line 482
```

Comment: That's pretty clear: `Permission denied`, `Please verify that the current setting 
of session.save_path is correct`

Comment: Hey Marcin, thanks for giving me an answer. This is the line notfied :

Comment: throw new Zend_Session_Exception(__CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . '() - ' . Zend_Session_Exception::$sessionStartError);

Comment: i dont see any errors :/...

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research i found the problem. Windows couldnt creat the "sess_9.." folder so i put this line in application.ini.

```
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
```

And now it's working perfectly !

Thanks for yours advices

Answer (score 0):

First Create folder "tmp" on your root directory with permission 777 then before start_session, Add below code in your Framework Loading Page Public / index.php Or in general you can set it in your apache server too.

```
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');
```

Comment: what is it supposed to do?